# How can i bind log() to my runtime in my unit test file?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, unittesting, chai

How can I make **log()** bind to my runtime in my chai unit-testing script?
I have a hardhat solidity project. Included snippets and pseudocode.
*This framework is very new to me so if there are obvious differences between a test and deploy script, please explain that.*

This **will output** to the console.
In my deploy script  **contract_deploy.js** i do this:

```js
...
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
...
log("Mocks deployed!")
```

This **will not output** to the console.
In my unit test file **Contract.test.js** script i try to extract **log** like this:

```js
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { log } = deployments
const { assert } = require("chai")

describe("Contract", async function () {
    let deployer
    beforeEach(async function () {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture("all")
        contract = await ethers.getContract("Contract", deployer)
    })

    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("Tests that the constructor works", async function () {

            // This does not output anything...
            log("Testing constructor..")
            
            assert.equal("1","1")
```